# Am Yisrael Genealogy

Tags: tanach, genealogy

I'm looking for a family tree that collects all of the genealogical records of Am Yisrael in the Tanach and also shows who was in the same generation as whom (for example, if I remember correctly, there are about 17 generations between Korach and Shmuel but between Nachshon and David there are only 4, yet David and Shmuel were contemporaries). Is there such a thing available somewhere?

Comment: I've seen books on this with hundreds of pages, but I don't remember what it's called. You want online or in print.

Comment: דוד בן ישי בן עובד בן בעז בן שלמון בן נחשון בן עמינדב בן רם בן חצרון בן פרץ בן יהודה בן יעקב בן יצחק בן אברהם

Comment: @robev online is preferable, but if not, then print.

Comment: Not 4 from nachaon to davi

Comment: @DoubleAA I wrote 4 *between*.

Comment: That is *not* normal english.

Comment: @DoubleAA when I learned English, between meant the middle section of two ends, not including the ends. You are certainly free to edit my question so it'll be proper. Edit also the part about Shmuel.

Comment: @Harel13 - I have from Adam to Pinchas if that is any help to you?

Comment: @Dov thanks. I'm more interested in the latter generations, though.

Comment: @Harel13 I figured

Comment: I saw something like what you want. I don't remember what the title was but it was a white book with all these kind of family trees

Comment: @Efraym Mossad Harav Kook's Da'at Mikrah possibly? I have access to that, but they don't have one that covers everyone at once. Actually, for the moment, I've decided to try to make my own, based on a few books. Of course, if there's one already out there, I'd be happy to hear about it. It's a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,
סדר הקורות בתנ"ך by אליעזר שולמן

Comment: (Note: as this is mainly an English site, it is recommended that you either write only in English or add English translations alongside the Hebrew). So this book has a family tree for all of the tribes through all of the Tanachic generations? I'll have to see if my yeshiva has it. Unfortunately, that'll probably only be next Elul.

Comment: I can't say all but it has a lot of great unique charts

Comment: Thanks, I hope I'll be able to get access to it soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve much of what you want with a very interactive and fun **3D Tanach Family Tree** with a timeline that can be accessed via the main menu of my very own [Base Hasefer](https://basehasefer.com) or even with a [direct link to the full-screen display](https://basehasefer.com/#/3Dtree).

To get a general sense of things, one can use their mouse to zoom in/out, pan and rotate the scene.

Hover over a person node to get extra information, click a node (or search/choose from a dropdown list) to select a person and then highlight the person's ancestors and/or descendants.

You can also fire a search from the selected person to find a list of times they are mentioned in Tanach.

A good option presented on the screen is the ability to filter people displayed based on selected sections of Tanach, eg.

- only show people mentioned in Parshas Bemidbar
- only show people mentioned in the first 3 perakim of Divrei Hayamim

One can even select a second person and generate a relation path between the two if it exists and then launch an animation that visually travels from one person to another person via their relation path.

The Tanach does implicitly define the entire path between Adam and Zerubavel (early period of the בית שני) so that is very worthwhile to check out [**a demo that travels this path**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gVGBEXmqQs).

The data upon which it rests is pretty good but far from perfect and I hope to improve things in the future.  Best used as a tool for getting a sense of the progression of who is related to whom throughout Tanach history and double-check the original pesukim if there is a doubt as to accuracy.  Also it only contains names and relations specifically mentioned in Tanach.  Maybe in the future it would also have an option to display relations that are על פי חז"ל and/or the מפרשים.